# Android custom widget based on existing widgets

Tags: android, widget, ondraw

I hope my problem will be understandable because I'm a Android beginner and English is not my native.

I would like create a custom widget which group a couple of TextView, ProgressBar and Button. The goal is to be able to declare my custom widget in a XML layout file with custom attributes which define buttons texts, etc ... But the disposition of inner Android widgets will be the same and defined in my class.

I have found how to declare custom attributes and create a custom widget, but I didn't found any documentation nor examples in the simple case of placement of existing Android widgets. I'am surprising so maybe I search in the wrong direction.

Below the simple code I am testing.

Custom class :

```
public class CastleViewItem extends View {

    private TextView item;

    public CastleViewItem (Context c, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(c, attributes);
        item = new TextView(c);
        TypedArray attrs = c.obtainStyledAttributes(attributes, R.styleable.CastleViewItem);
        item.setText(attrs.getString(R.styleable.CastleViewItem_name).toString());
 }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas); 
        // I suppose there is some code to add here.
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(200, 200);
        // item.getWidth()/item.getHeight() return 0, so I fixed temporarily the value to ensure 
        // the widget will be displayed.
    }
}
```

XML custom attributes declaration :

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CastleViewItem">
        <attr name="name" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

XML layout file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ffbdx="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/bdx.fleurey"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <bdx.fleurey.CastleViewItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ffbdx:name="Moat" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This code display nothing.
I hope I was quite clear, thanks in advance for your answers/advices.